# Remove elements from request before processing the form

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-forms, symfony-2.5

I'm creating a simple CRUD for managing users of one application. Users are created and managed by `FOSUserBundle`. In addition I do not allow anyone to edit/change the `username` and the `email` so I do not show these fields in the form being edited. This is the code with which I'm handling the editing:

```
// Create the form and set the right data
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($id);

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('update-user', array('id' => $id)),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'user' => $user
    );
}

// Perform the update action and do the rest of the logic
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id = NULL)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $em->getRepository("UserBundle:User")->find($id);

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $response = array();
    $response['status'] = TRUE;

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $userManager->updateUser($user);
        $response['message'] = $this->get('translator')->trans('update.success', array('%element%' => 'el usuario'));
    }
    else
    {
        $response['message'] = $this->get('translator')->trans('update.fail', array('%element%' => 'el usuario'));
        $response['error'] = $this->getFormErrors($form);
        $this->get('ladybug')->log($response['error']);
        $response['status'] = FALSE;
    }

    return new JsonResponse($response);
}
```

But since `username` and `email` fields are not present and somehow they are getting to the update action, where these fields are updated with blank values​​. The only thing I can think to solve this problem is to delete this parameters from the request before making the `handleRequest` but I have no idea how, any help?

PS: Any ideas better than mine or any suggestion on the code is welcome!!

**1st test**

I thought the problem is the `fos_user.user_manager`. Why? Take a look at this:

```
// Unset non editable fields from $request
unset(
        $request->get('user')['username'], $request->get('user')['email']
);

// Continue the flow
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

But surprisingly this throws this "weird" error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE fos_user SET username =
>   ?, username_canonical = ?, email = ?, email_canonical = ?, password =
>   ?, roles = ?, updatedAt = ? WHERE id = ?' with params [null, null,
>   null, null,
>   "tD9GEdMpFT3j75fPeoEkus00ge+xmrgQhaXntNstz7taSx4KAdqpKGhxfC3czHaNr17pGfrigylT29iyTfcZNA==",
>   "a:1:{i:0;s:16:\"ROLE_PROFILE_TWO\";}", "2014-09-13 21:01:10", 4]:

Which leads to this:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '' for key 'UNIQ_957A647992FC23A8'

Is the problem there? `username` is unique and, I don't know why yet, still trying to set `username` and `email` with blank values causing the error above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can include them in your form populated by php, and make them hidden. Or pass them through in $_SESSION variables to be later populated in your function.

Comment: @jjonesdesign make them hidden doesn't work, still updating as blank values

Comment: Are they hidden, but still being filled with a value before sendoff?

Comment: @jjonesdesign my bad, they are not hidden the input is disabled so users can not edit, but yes still updating with blank values

Comment: leave them enabled, Hide them, and populate them before send off. This still does not work? Is it possible they are being overwritten apon being received before you use them?

Comment: @jjonesdesign that solution works but I'll wait until a nice and clean solution, I don't like this one so much and I'll use just in no other come up but anyway many thanks man

Comment: Can you not simply remove username and email from your SET?

Comment: @jjonesdesign is not so easy, take a look to this lines `$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');  $userManager->updateUser($user);` that tells the update is handle by `userManager` and not by setting each property

Comment: Do you actually need to use UserManager?  You can treat the User entity like any other, and make whatever changes you like (without any danger of the Manager doing things you don't like...).  It would be a couple of extra lines, to get an EntityManager, `persist` and `flush`.